# What will happen if I enable HTTP/2 in Nginx without web app supporting it?

Tags: http, nginx, http2

I have Nginx 1.9.5 installed which has HTTP/2 support. My website is running in a **uWSGI** container, and uWSGI **doesn't** support HTTP/2 for now.

If I enable HTTP/2 for Nginx, my assets will definitely load faster since I'm serving them on my own server using Nginx. What I want to know is if my website will still work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.

Nginx just like a diplomatist, web users don't know the inner, and they don't need to care the inner, Nginx was responsible for the request from outside, and send the same message to your inner container.

HTTP/2.0 works well no matter your container communicate with Nginx via HTTP or uWSGI. It only be used between Nginx and your users.

Comment: App communicate with Nginx via wsgi protocol, I'm not sure it works.

Comment: HTTP/2.0 protocol only be used between users and Nginx, no matter which protocol App communicate with Nginx, if your App works before this, so does it via HTTP/2.0. :-)